# What does the donation machine do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I found a donation machine in a shop.

[image: DONATION]

What does it do apart from take my money, if anything? I noticed it seems to break after a few coins.

Comment: It stacks over multiple runs. So far I'm over 200 coins and stuff keeps unlocking regularly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edmund explains it [here](http://bindingofisaac.com/post/86267138574/charity), basically it slowly upgrades the store, sort of leveling it up to have more items, etc.

Comment: I forget what amount of coins got me my first shop upgrade, but it's 100 (total) coins for the 2nd one.

Comment: @Fambida It's 20 coins for the first shop upgrade.

Answer (score 6):

Donation machine can unlock certain items and upgrade your shop, allowing it to sell more items.

List of unlockable stuff:

- 10 Coins: Blue Map
- 20 Coins: Shop Upgraded to level 2
- 50 Coins: There's Option (An Item)
- 100 Coins: Shop Upgrade to level 3
- 150 Coins: Black Candle
- 200 Coins: Shop Upgrade to level 4
- 400 Coins: Red Candle
- 600 Coins: Shop Upgrade to level 5 (Last level for the shop)
- 900 Coins: The Candle
- 999 Coins: Stop Watch

In the Afterbirth DLC, you can also find the Greed Machine, which can unlock items and achievements. It appears after Ultra Greed Fight

List of unlocks from the Greed Machine:

- 1 Coin: Lucky Pennies
- 15 Coins: Special Hanging Shopkeepers
- 33 Coins: Wooden Nickel
- 68 Coins: Cain Now Holds Paper Clip
- 111 Coins: Everything Is Terrible 2
- 234 Coins: Special Shoopkeeper
- 439 Coins: Eve Holds Razor Blade
- 666 Coins: Store Key
- 879 Coins: The Lost Now Hold Holy Mantle
- 999 Coins: Generousity Achievement
- 1000 Coins: The Keeper Is Unlocked! (It's a character)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to upgrading the shop, you can also use a bomb on it to get some coins out of the donated money pool. Especially useful if you only need a few coins to buy that shop item.

[image]

<sup>It seems that using a bomb "destroys" some coins</sup>

Comment: "Especially useful if you are only need a few coins to buy that shop upgrade." ...no it isn't, as the amount of coins in the donation machine goes down every time you bomb it.  If you have 18 coins and bomb it to get 3 coins, putting those 3 coins back in... will bring it back up to 18 because it dropped to 15 when you bombed it.  Or did you mean "shop item" instead of upgrade?

Comment: @Powerlord - Yeah, excuse me, I meant shop item. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You can however abuse the donating if you have Humbling bundle, as the coins dropped by bombing the machine will be doubled.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that the number of coins donated remains from run to run, and when it reached 10 I got the secret "The Blue Map has Appeared in the Basement!"  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: It carries between runs. That is an important feature because some items require over 200 cents, and the thing jams (maybe for the rest of the run) after putting in a random amount of money.