# Does continuing to donate past 999 achieve anything?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Related question - [What does the donation machine do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190525/what-does-the-donation-machine-do)

In BoI: Rebirth, you can donate to a machine in the shop room, and as you put in more and more money, you can unlock things.

When you hit 999 coins in the machine, you unlock an item and the machine blows up. I figured that was the end of that.

However, on my next playthrough, the machine was back! So I have dutifully been feeding more money into it. However I'm up to a couple of hundred gold in there now and it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Am I wasting my money? Or will this 2nd round of donating eventually unlock something awesome?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't unlock anything else, but not sure enough to answer. There is the added benefit of being able "store" coins in it between runs!

Comment: @Telestia you are right, that's the only use for now (except if afterbirth adds something when it comes out)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It won't unlock anything, all you can do is use it as a bank for future runs.

The blowing up was not caused by adding your 999th cent, that was because you got it to 1000 cents.

So in a way you are wasting your money (if you donate money instead of buying stuff anyway), in a way your are giving later runs a potentially bigger chance for buying items (assuming you bomb the machine in that run).

Comment: This is true, but you'd have to spend a lot of money in order for that to matter. I made a shop breakdown for anyone who cares (http://pastebin.com/Ek5WaJXt), and no it's not professional, but it gives you an idea. A sketchy one at best.

Comment: @Scootaloo Your breakdown lacks of the assumption that most of the time when you bomb a donation machine it spits out some coins, but can deplete the counter by more coins you actually get, e.g: the machine spits out 2 coins, but the counter is decremented by 4.

Comment: @Asunez AFAIK bombing the machine always wastes exactly 1 coin. and results in 2-6 coins flying out.

Comment: @Arperum If by "wastes exactly 1 coin" you mean that "for **n** coins dropped, **n+1** coins are deducted from machine" you are right. As per [BoI: Rebirth Wikipedia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Donation_Machine) - "The Donation Machine can be bombed, causing it to randomly drop between 2 to 5 coins each time. Coins will be deducted from the machine's total every time this occurs. However, coins are not deducted at a 1 to 1 ratio; one more coin is deducted than are actually dropped on the ground."

Comment: @Asunez That's exactly what I mean. I thought the upper limit was 6 dropped, I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't unlock anything, according to [BoI: Rebirth wiki](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Donation_Machine#Strategy).

Moreover, it's not recommended to add a 1000th cent to the Donation Machine and make it blow up. That's a huge waste of pennies! Because if you destroy it the machine will only drop a bunch of dimes that you have to use in that run and the penny counter will restart from 0 in the next one.

So it's better to keep the Donation Machine as a *penny-bank* that exchanges "bombs for money".